# how to deal with a big matrix or data.frame in R

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata

I am trying to assign values to a "10000000*6" logical matrix. The process would be 1)create a matrix; 2) then assign the value to each element of the matrix.To simplify my question, I just show how one value get assigned to one element of the matrix.

Here are the codes:

```
m <- matrix(data = NA, ncol= 6, nrow= 10000000)
m[1,1] <- 1
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 228.9 Mb

There is no error when creating the "10000000*6" logical matrix, but there is when assigning the values.

I also tried to do the same tasks but with a smaller matrix (100*6). Things work well.

Here are the codes:

```
m <- matrix(data = NA, ncol= 6, nrow= 100)
m[1,1] <- 1
```

Could anyone help me to deal with the bigger matrix?

Answer (score 7):

It may come as a bit of a surprise but R is a bit of a procrastinator. It is possible that a command to "create" an object may not actually do so until there is a real demand for action, such as populating a matrix with a "real" value. The term to describe this is "pass-by-promise". Furthermore, assignment to an existing object may construct duplicates or even triplicates of the object which will occupy space until they are garbage collected.

So here's what you do. Exit out of R. Power down. Restart your system with a minimum of other applications, since they all take memory. Restart R and run your commands. I predict success if you have the typical 4GB memory available before system load. 228.9 Mb is not really very big, but in your case it was the straw that broke the camel's back. R needs to be able to find contiguous memory for each object and garbage collection will typically not defragment memory.